# R create data frame listing all factor levels - better way of doing this?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to produce a data frame with columns for:

1. The name of each factor from another data frame
2. Each level of each factor
3. The corresponding level number.

I was eventually able to come up with the code below, which just about works, but it seems a bit complicated (my R experience is rather limited and much googling was involved). What problems are there with my code, and is there a better way of generating the same output in the same format?

```
mydata <- iris

#Get vector of column types
type <- sapply(mydata,class)
# Filter out just the ones that are factors
factors = type[type=="factor"]
# Allocate a vector to hold 1 data frame per factor
listOfFactors <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(factors))

# For each factor, list all the levels of that factor, and the level number
for (j in 1:length(factors)) {
    cur_colname <- names(factors[j])
    cur_colnum <- which(colnames(mydata)==cur_colname)
    cur_nlevels <- nlevels(mydata[,cur_colnum])
    listOfFactors[[j]] <- data.frame(VarName=character(cur_nlevels),
                                     Level=character(cur_nlevels),
                                     Number=integer(cur_nlevels),
                                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE
                                     )
    for (i in 1:cur_nlevels) {
          cur_level <- levels(mydata[,cur_colnum])[i]
        listOfFactors[[j]]$VarName[i] <- cur_colname
        listOfFactors[[j]]$Level[i] <- cur_level
        listOfFactors[[j]]$Number[i] <- i
    }
}

allfactorlevels <- do.call("rbind", listOfFactors)
```

Comment: Have a look at expand.grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you don't make use of vectorized operations. It can be tricky when transitioning from other languages, but for-loops are almost never the answer in R, especially when you use them to access elements of a vector/list/dataframe one at a time. I have kept the first part of your code, and then made a (much) more consise approach in getting the output.

```
type <- sapply(mydata,class)
factors = type[type=="factor"]
```

Now I use 'lapply' to iterate over the *names* of your factor columns. This means I can use those names to access the original dataframe and extract the information we need.

```
output <- lapply(names(factors),function(x){
  res <- data.frame(VarName=x, 
                    Level=levels(mydata[,x]), 
                    Number=1:nlevels(mydata[,x]))
  return(res)
})
```

Creating a dataframe is then easy:

```
do.call(rbind, output)
```

Comment: Is the object `res` somehow local to the function definition?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way with `dplyr` functions: select the factor variables, create a data frame of factor levels and numbers for each, then bind those data frames back together. `purrr::map_dfr` will do this iteration and add an ID variable to the resulting data frame; in this case, it's the name of the original variable.

I'm adding another factor column to the data in order to better illustrate and test.

```r
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- iris %>%
  mutate(Group = as.factor(sample(letters[1:4], nrow(.), replace = TRUE)))

mydata %>%
  select(where(is.factor)) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(function(f) {
    data.frame(Level = levels(f),
               Number = seq_along(levels(f)))
  }, .id = "VarName")
#>   VarName      Level Number
#> 1 Species     setosa      1
#> 2 Species versicolor      2
#> 3 Species  virginica      3
#> 4   Group          a      1
#> 5   Group          b      2
#> 6   Group          c      3
#> 7   Group          d      4
```